# org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion exception in WAS server

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

we are working on java rest web service we are using the below jars

```
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
org.json-20120521.jar
```

Using the above jars below code is working fine in tomcat server.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
String userJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(userJSON);
JSONObject userJsonObj = new JSONObject(userJsonString);
```

While deploying this in WAS server we have got the below error:

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion&#40;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize$Inclusion&#59;&#41;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper&#59;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the jars it looks like you are using codehaus jackson: https://github.com/codehaus/jackson/ instead of fasterxml jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson. With codehaus jackson your code will look like:
`objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

It may be Jackson versions collision. Check if WAS contains Jackson jars in its classpath (libraries)

Comment: this has been fairly common in my experience, especially between 2.x and 1.x versions.

Comment: OK.We have searched in the classpath IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/Lib.am I rite?

Comment: I haven't use WAS. Search in all subdirectories in IBM/WebSphere. Also check if your application archive (war or ear) doesn't have duplicated Jackson jars.